# How can I replace a character in an OnChanging event using Regex and keeping the caret at the end of the EditText in ExtendScript?

Tags: regex, extendscript, caret

I need to type in a TextBox and see instantly the result in a StaticText. In order to avoid " " (space character), I'm replacing it using Regex.
It is working but the cursor moves to the left every time when a space key is pressed. It is being replaced by "_" but because the cursor moves to the first position in my EditText box, it makes impossible to proceed typing fluently.

```
editText.onChanging = function(){
  if (this.text.match(/\s*$/i)) {
    this.text = this.text.replace(/ /g, "_");
  }
  staticText.text = this.text;
}
```

How can I type in that edittext, replacing every space character and keeping the cursor at the end of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

To replace a character using Regex and keep the caret at the end of the line, you should save the result from the replacement in a variable, clear the text box and use a textselection to bring it back to your edittext box.

```
editText.onChanging = function(){    
     if (this.text.match(/\s*$/i)) {    
          var text = this.text.replace(/ /g, "_");  
          this.text = "";  
          this.textselection = text;  
     }  
     staticText.text = this.text;    
}
```